# Copy values from array into register in inline NASM

Tags: arrays, x86, nasm

I usually can find all necessary info from google and other stackoverflow question, but now I need a help. I use inline assembly in Visual Studio, my task: find 5 consecutive elements in array which sum is K (and then delete). Firstly I create an array and get K in C++ part

```
unsigned int *arr;
    int k,n;
    std::cout<<"How many elements? ";
    std::cin>>n;
    arr=new unsigned int[n];
    std::cout<<"Enter array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        std::cin>>arr[i];
    std::cout<<"Enter k: ";
    std::cin>>k;
```

Then I find a group of element into asm

```
xor ebx,ebx ;ebx - counter from 0 to n-4
        lea esi,[arr]
        FindGroup:
            mov eax,[esi+ebx*4]
            add eax,[esi+(ebx+1)*4]
            add eax,[esi+(ebx+2)*4]
            add eax,[esi+(ebx+3)*4]
            add eax,[esi+(ebx+4)*4]
            cmp eax,k
            je DeleteGroup
            inc ebx
            jmp FindGroup
```

So my code doesn't work as I expected. Windows Debugger shows that eax store large number but not first element of array (and not esi value). I tried use **[arr+ebx*4]** and **arr[ebx*4]** instead of **[esi+ebx*4]**, but it neither work. Where should I search a problem?

Comment: MSVC inline asm uses MASM-like syntax, not NASM.  But anyway, `int *arr` is a *pointer* variable not an array.  You want the value of the pointer (address of the array), not the address where the pointer itself is stored.

Comment: Seems to me that `lea esi,[arr]` should be `mov esi,[arr]` since `arr` is a pointer to an array not the address of the start of the array.

Comment: @PeterCordes @MichaelPetch Thanks! I replaced `lea esi,[arr]` with `mov esi,arr` and `add eax,[esi+(ebx+1)*4]` with `add eax,[esi+4*ebx+4]` and so on. Now the loop works correctly

Comment: N.B. If you initialize `eax` with `arr[0]+...+arr[4] - k` you can in each loop calculate `arr[i+5]-arr[i]` (using a `mov` and `sub` into another register), add that result to `eax` and jump to `DeleteGroup` if that result is zero (no additional comparison necessary, and much fewer additions per loop -- especially no 7 instruction dependency-chain). You can also increment `esi` by 4, instead of using `ebx` to get simpler addresses for the input (not sure how much this effects performance nowadays).

Comment: Also, as it is written, your loop is not guaranteed to terminate. You could add additional elements `k, 0, 0, 0, 0` to the end, which would guarantee that the loop eventually terminates. Otherwise, you should compare `ebx` to `n` or `esi` to `arr+4*n` before branching to the start of the loop.